# can I use the authorization in a web.config file inside a folder with my custom authentication system

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config, authorization, login-control

I built my own authentication system, that basically check if a email and password exist in a table, and if they do,  some values are stored in session state like id of the user and etc. I 'd like to know if I can use a web.config file in a folder to prevent undesired users from accessing sections of the site that they shouldn't. I am just asking ]if it is possible.

Comment: you can use membership in asp.net

Answer (score 0):

after a long search on google I found the answer. Use Formsauthentication.setauthcookie And the feature works as if you were using a login control.